# chrome loads my page, firefox doesn't

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to echo php in a web page via an HTML form (`test_form.php` --> `test.php`). The form allows users to pick a date and time. I'll show the code for `test_form.php` and `test.php` below.

This works in Chrome (linux) -- my script checks that the date and hour are set, then echoes the date and hour in the browser.

But it doesn't work in Firefox (linux) or Safari (Mac).

In Firefox, I get a blank page. When I view the page source I see the echoed stuff -- except it tells me that date and hour are NOT set!

Has anyone experienced this? Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

thanks in advance.

test_form.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'> 
    <title>Select date a d/or time</title> 
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/1.4.5/jqm-datebox-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/external/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/js/doc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/1.4.5/jqm-datebox-1.4.5.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/1.4.5/jqm-datebox-1.4.5.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/1.4.5/jqm-datebox-1.4.5.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/1.4.5/jqm-datebox-1.4.5.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/1.4.5/jqm-datebox-1.4.5.mode.slidebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/1.4.5/jqm-datebox-1.4.5.mode.customflip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jtsage.com/datebox/i18n/jqm-datebox.lang.utf8.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile,
    {
      ajaxEnabled: false
    });

 function checkForm(form)
  {
    // validation fails if the input is blank
    if(form.hour.value == "") {
      alert("Error: Please select an hour!");
      form.hour.focus();
      return false;
    }

    // regular expression to match only digits (0-24)
    var re = /0|(0[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-4]))/;

    // validation fails if the input doesn't match our regular expression
    if(!re.test(form.hour.value)) {
      alert("Error: Input contains invalid characters!");
      form.hour.focus();
      return false;
    }

    // validation was successful
    return true;
  }


    </script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role='page'>
    <a href='#' data-rel='back' class='ui-btn ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all  ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-inline'  data-role='button' role='button' data-inline='true'>Back</a>
    <a href='#popupNested' data-role='button' class=' ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-btn-icon-notext  ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-inline' data-transition='turn' data-rel='popup' data-inline='true'>Date/time</a>

<div data-role='popup' id='popupNested' data-theme='none'>
    <div data-role='collapsibleset' data-theme='a' data-content-theme='a' data-collapsed-icon='arrow-r' data-expanded-icon='arrow-d' style='margin:0; width:250px;'>
        <div data-role='collapsible' data-inset='false'>
        <h2>Hourly</h2>
            <ul data-role='listview'>
                <li><a href='Manyhour_today_form.php' data-rel='dialog' data-role='date'>Pick an hour from today</a></li>
                <li><a href='Manyhour_form.php' data-rel='dialog'>Pick hour from previous day</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /collapsible -->
        <div data-role='collapsible' data-inset='false'>
        <h2>Daily</h2>
            <ul data-role='listview'>
                <li><a href='Mtoday_POG.php'>So far today</a></li>
                <li><a href='Manyday_form.php' data-rel='dialog'>Choose a previous day</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /collapsible -->
          <ul data-role='listview'>
                <li><a href='Manymonth_form.php' data-rel='dialog'>Monthly</a></li>
                <li><a href='Manyyear_form.php' data-rel='dialog'>Yearly</a></li>
            </ul>


    </div><!-- /collapsible set -->
</div><!-- /popup -->
    <div data-role='content' style='width:50%'>

                        <form action='test.php' method='post' onsubmit='return checkForm(this);'>
                        <label for'date'><strong>Select a date and hour</strong></label>
            <input type="text" name='date' data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox","calUsePickers": true, "calYearPickMin":2008, "calYearPickMax":"NOW", "beforeToday": true, "overrideDateFormat": "%Y-%m-%d"}'  placeholder='click icon to select date'/>

            <input type="text" name='hour' data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timeflipbox","minuteStep":60, "overrideTimeFormat": "%H", "overrideTimeOutput": "%H"}'  placeholder='click icon to select hour' required="required"/>

            <input type ='submit' name= 'submit' value='submit'>
           </form>
    </div>


</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

... and test.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');


if(isset($_POST['date']))
{
$date = $_POST['date'];$date = str_replace("-","",$date);echo "date IS set, and it is ".$date."<br>";
}
else {
$date = "20150101"; echo "date variable not set";
}

if(isset($_POST['hour']))
{
$hour = $_POST['hour']; echo "hour IS set! And it is ".$hour."<br>";
if($hour == "00"){$hour =24;}
} 
else {
$hour = "01"; echo "hour variable is not set";
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you debug and temporarily change the `method="post"` with `method="get"`, and see if the date/hour arguments are visible in the URL (Firefox/Linux, Safari/Max)?

Comment: interesting, and thanks for your reply. So I changed 'post' to 'get' as you asked, and Chrome still output the echo but this time date and hour were not set (both ifs evaluated to false). Firefox still echoed an empty screen and "view page source" showed the same as when 'get' was 'post -- the ifs were false. Safari (Epiphany in Ubuntu) just showed an empty screen. Everything in Linux.

Comment: It is normal that it doesn't work anymore for any browser, but I want you to look to the URL in the address bar after you submit: what does it say for Firefox? Do you see the submitted date and hour values in the URL? Any difference you notice in that URL when compared to Chrome? This is just a test to make sure both browser submit exactly the same to the server.

Comment: actually I failed to change 'post' to 'get' in test.php. When I did: Chrome still output the echo with both ifs evaluating to true. Firefox still echoed an empty screen but "view page source" showed what I wanted it to echo -- the ifs were true. Safari (Epiphany in Ubuntu) just showed an empty screen. Everything in Linux.

Comment: in firefox address bar it says "localhost/etc/test.php?date=2015-09-07&hour=18&submit=submit"... chrome address bar says the same thing, and Epiphany says the same thing.

Comment: Honestly, I am out of clues, if with `get` you see exactly the same URL appearing in the three browsers, then with `post` the `PHP` code should also respond the same way for these browsers, meaning the `if` conditions should give the same result in all three cases. If I were you I would in `PHP` do a `var_dump($_POST)` as see what you get for the three browsers (with `post` method).